# Charts not compile on Xcode 14

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing following errors in library -

1. Type 'ChartDataSet' does not conform to protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollection'
2. Unavailable instance method 'replaceSubrange(_:with:)' was used to satisfy a requirement of protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollection'.

My code is :

```
extension ChartDataSet: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    public func append(_ newElement: Element) {
        calcMinMax(entry: newElement)
        entries.append(newElement)
    }

    public func remove(at position: Index) -> Element {
        let element = entries.remove(at: position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        return element
    }

    public func removeFirst() -> Element {
        let element = entries.removeFirst()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        return element
    }

    public func removeFirst(_ n: Int) {
        entries.removeFirst(n)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    public func removeLast() -> Element {
        let element = entries.removeLast()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        return element
    }

    public func removeLast(_ n: Int) {
        entries.removeLast(n)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    public func removeSubrange<R>(_ bounds: R) where R : RangeExpression, Index == R.Bound {
        entries.removeSubrange(bounds)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @objc
    public func removeAll(keepingCapacity keepCapacity: Bool) {
        entries.removeAll(keepingCapacity: keepCapacity)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Please help me to optimize my code according to latest libraries of xcode 14.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [RangeReplaceableCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection), the one method you must implement is `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` and your code does not seem to provide that method. You should ensure the method exists and that it is declared `public` like the other methods.

> To add `RangeReplaceableCollection` conformance to your custom collection, add an empty initializer and the `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` method to your custom type.

Answer (score 0):

juste Add **repalceSubrange** function in **ChartDataSet** extension

```
public func replaceSubrange<C>(_ subrange: Swift.Range<Int>, with newElements: C) where C : Collection, ChartDataEntry == C.Element {
            entries.replaceSubrange(subrange, with: newElements)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```